# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Future<dynamic>', is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope someone will be able to help me with the custom widget below. As a tool I user FlutterFlow to No-Code with Flutter, but it is possible to create custom widgets as I am trying below. I am using an action as a parameter, but I have no clue how to solve the issue that is mentioned by FlutterFlow in the Screenshot. Can any of you shine a light on this case?[image]

````dart
class SlideToCommit extends StatefulWidget {
  const SlideToCommit({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.label,
    this.icon,
    required this.action,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final Widget? label;
  final Widget? icon;
  final Future<dynamic> Function() action;

  @override
  _SlideToCommitState createState() => _SlideToCommitState();
}

class _SlideToCommitState extends State<SlideToCommit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderButton(
        action: () async {
          print("test");
        },

        ///Put label over here
        label: Text(
          "Slide to commit",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff4a4a4a),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 17),
        ),
        icon: Center(
            child: Icon(
          Icons.power_settings_new,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 40.0,
          semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
        )));
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `action` as a `Future` meaning that an async method must be there. You can do that by adding the async keyword like this:

```
action: () async {

},
```

But you have another problem as well. You are returning another `SliderButton` inside the build of your `SliderButton` state, meaning you you will get an infinite recursion

Comment: Hi Ivo! I see how I made a mistake with naming my class as SliderButton as well, but after adjustments to the code I still can't get it to work somehow... Do you have an idea what the problem can be? I have edited the code in my question.

Comment: @RoRoStudio You shouldn't edit your question for answering another question. It makes the current answers invalid. If you have a new question you should ask a new question with details of your problem

Comment: That is a valid point you have there.

Answer (score 2):

Because you init declare action with Future, so you need to add async to it, change

```
action: ()  {

},
```

to

```
action: () async  {

},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SliderButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliderButton({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.label,
    this.icon,
    required this.action,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final Widget? label;
  final Widget? icon;
  final Future<dynamic> Function() action;

  @override
  _SliderButtonState createState() => _SliderButtonState();
}

class _SliderButtonState extends State<SliderButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderButton(
        action: ()async {
          ///What to add here?
        },

        ///Put label over here
        label: Text(
          "Slide to commit",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff4a4a4a),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 17),
        ),
        icon: Center(
            child: Icon(
          Icons.power_settings_new,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 40.0,
          semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
        )));
  }
}
```

***async**

Answer (score 1):

> //What to add here?

you have a action property. use it

```
return SliderButton(
        action: () async{
          widget.action();
       }
```

#### please rename you class name, because your package also named `SliderButton`. its quite confusing's